# how to return -1 as char in java

Tags: java

I want to return -1 as a char

```
static char nonrepeatingCharacter(String S)
{
    ArrayList<Character> al = new ArrayList<Character>();
    
    for(int i=0; i<S.length(); i++){
        if(!al.contains(S.charAt(i))){
            al.add(S.charAt(i));
        }
        else{
            al.remove(Character.valueOf(S.charAt(i)));
        }
    }
    
    if(al.size() == 0){
        // Here I want to return -1
    }
    
    return al.get(0);
}
```

Comment: You mean `(char) -1`? Or do you mean you want to represent the string `-1` as a char?

Comment: `char` is an _unsigned_ 16-bit integer. It can't have the literal value `-1`. Note that doing `(char) -1` will give you the `char` for `65535`.

Comment: The appropriate way is to use `int` as the return type. That is also what Java does in - for example - [`Reader.read()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/io/Reader.html#read()).

Comment: So if [method parameter] `S` contains more than one non-repeating character, you want method `nonrepeatingCharacter` to return just one of them? Can `S` contain any valid character, including non-printable characters such as [unicode] null, i.e. 0 (zero)?

Comment: You should in any case be working with *codepoints* these days. When you do, your problem disappears

Comment: Note that this doesn't return a non-repeating character, it returns a character with odd parity (it occurs 1, 3, 5 etc times)

Answer (score 4):

You can't directly return -1 as a char because char in Java is unsigned and doesn't support negative values. If you want to return -1, you need to change the return type of your method to int:

```
static int nonrepeatingCharacter(String S)
{
    ArrayList<Character> al = new ArrayList<Character>();
    
    for(int i=0; i<S.length(); i++){
        if(!al.contains(S.charAt(i))){
            al.add(S.charAt(i));
        }
        else{
            al.remove(Character.valueOf(S.charAt(i)));
        }
    }
    
    if(al.size() == 0){
        return -1;
    }
    
    return al.get(0);
}
```

Then your function call would look like below:

```
int result = nonrepeatingCharacter("someString");

if (result == -1) {
    // ...
} else {
    char nonRepeatingChar = (char) result;
}
```

A more modern aproach would be to use Optional:

```
static Optional<Character> nonrepeatingCharacter(String S) {
    ArrayList<Character> al = new ArrayList<Character>();
    
    for(int i = 0; i < S.length(); i++) {
        if(!al.contains(S.charAt(i))) {
            al.add(S.charAt(i));
        } else {
            al.remove(Character.valueOf(S.charAt(i)));
        }
    }
    
    if(al.size() == 0) {
        return Optional.empty();
    }
    
    return Optional.of(al.get(0));
}
```

and its usage:

```
Optional<Character> result = nonrepeatingCharacter("someString");

if (result.isPresent()) {
    char nonRepeatingChar = result.get();
    // ...
} else {
    // ...
}
```

This way your code will be less error prone.

Finally, to make your function be compliant with full Unicode range, you should switch to using code points, this will also allow you to return -1:

```
static int nonrepeatingCodePoint(String S) {
    ArrayList<Integer> al = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < S.length(); ) {
        int codePoint = S.codePointAt(i);

        if (!al.contains(codePoint)) {
            al.add(codePoint);
        } else {
            al.remove(Integer.valueOf(codePoint));
        }

        i += Character.charCount(codePoint);
    }

    if (al.size() == 0) {
        return -1;
    }

    return al.get(0);
}
```

char type in java represents only BMP part of Unicode, which are characters from U+0000 to U+FFFF. For characters outside BMP (U+010000 to U+10FFFF) single character is represented as pair of chars. So, to correctly work with all possible characters, you should
work with pairs of chars:

```
char[] chars = Character.toChars(codePoint);
```

Comment: Note that you don't usually want Optional for primitives though - the Optional code is both way more code, and can't compile to the plain value comparison that the int compare gives us.

Comment: Agreed, using Optional with primitives can introduce additional overhead, whereas a simple int comparison is more efficient and straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to return a 'mark' value when `al.size() == 0`. You can do it like this:

```java
static Character nonrepeatingCharacter(String S)
{
    ArrayList<Character> al = new ArrayList<Character>();
    
    for(int i=0; i<S.length(); i++){
        if(!al.contains(S.charAt(i))){
            al.add(S.charAt(i));
        }
        else{
            al.remove(Character.valueOf(S.charAt(i)));
        }
    }
    
    if(al.size() == 0){
        return null;
    }
    
    return al.get(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Bearing in mind my previous comment, you could try something like:

```
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.*;

public class Grin {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String s = "-example";
        if (args.length > 0) {
            s = args[0];
        }
        int n = Grin.getFirstNonRepeatingCharacter(s);
        if (n > -1) {
            System.out.printf("The first non-repeating character is '%s'%n", new String(new int[] { n }, 0, 1));
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("No non-repeating");
        }
    }

    public static int getFirstNonRepeatingCharacter(String s) {
        Map<Integer, Long> m = s.codePoints().boxed().collect(
            groupingBy(i ->i, 
            LinkedHashMap<Integer, Long>::new,
            counting()));
        Optional<Integer> codePoint = m.entrySet().stream()
            .filter(e -> 1 == e.getValue())
            .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
            .findFirst();
        return codePoint.isPresent()? codePoint.get() : -1;
    }
}
```

With no arguments, prints '' UPDATE: although the previous code illustrated the point about codepoints and -1, it wasn't really accurate, so I've now updated it.